# Auto detect city and match with Database in Laravel with Google Geolocation API

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3, laravel-5, geolocation, google-places-api

I'm building a Real Estate App with Google Map Search functionality. The customer can register and view the property listings. Customer needs to select a city to register.

I've added 2 tables to store provinces & cities manually. Here are the tables:

Province table:

`id  |   name   | country_id | short_name  |
---------------|------------|-------------|
1   | Ontario  |  1         |  ON         |
2   | Quebec   |  1         |  QC         |`

And the City Table:

`id  |   name   | province_id |
---------------|-------------|
1   | Toronto  |  1          |
1   | Ottawa   |  1          |
2   | Montréal |  2          |`

Now, the client has changed his requirement and want to add the city automatically when a customer register.
I've added google geolocation to the site. I can retrieve customer location & city but, sometimes it doesn't match with the list of cities in my database.

Is there any easy way to implement this functionality. Please help & Suggest.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: When you say it doesn't match, do you mean there are not similarities between both texts. You may consider using *LIKE* clause in your query over an exact match.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule Thanks for your nice comment. I've manually inserted all the cities name into the Database. And from the Google Geolocation API I've used `administrative_area_level_1` to get the city name. It doesn't match with the City Name I've added into the database for some Locations in google map. I'll be glad to get any suggestions about this. Thanks again!